# When heights of items near top of the ListView.builder are cached but have changed, how to get normal behavior from animateTo?

Tags: flutter, listview, infinite-scroll

#### Minimal Example

I've created a minimal example where every time an item is clicked, the list scrolls to exactly the top of that item. At the same time, the list can change from having headers to not having headers.

#### What's wrong?

If, as you scroll down the list, you keep headers on or keep headers off, there's nothing wrong. The bad behavior occurs when you toggle headers while a good ways down the list. Some items above the firstIndex of the cacheExtent will not be rebuilt, and will therefore the scroll offset will be off by that many header heights.

[image]

And here's the code for the example:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp(
    items: List<String>.generate(10000, (i) => 'Item $i'),
  ));
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<String> items;
  MyApp({Key? key, required this.items}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  final _scrollController = ScrollController();
  List<bool> hasHeaders = [true, false];
  int selectedIndex = 0;

  Widget _headerR = Container(
    height: 50,
    color: Colors.amber,
    child: Text('header'),
  );

  Widget _item({required int index}) {
    bool isSelected = index == selectedIndex;
    void _handleItemTap() {
      setState(() {
        print('setting index to $index');
        selectedIndex = index;
      });
      double futureOffset = 100.0 * index;
      if (hasHeaders[0]) {
        futureOffset += (index + 1) * 50;
      }
      Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 500), () {
        _scrollController.animateTo(futureOffset,
            duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500), curve: Curves.easeOut);
        print('scrolling to $futureOffset');
      });
    }

    return Container(
      height: 100.0,
      color: isSelected ? Colors.green : Colors.white,
      child: Material(
        color: isSelected ? Colors.green : Colors.white,
        child: InkWell(
          onTap: _handleItemTap,
          child: ListTile(
            title: Text('${widget.items[index]}'),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _itemBuilder(BuildContext context, int index) {
    if (hasHeaders[0]) {
      return Column(
        children: [_headerR, _item(index: index)],
      );
    } else {
      return _item(index: index);
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final title = 'Long List';

    return MaterialApp(
      title: title,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(title),
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: [
            Flexible(
              flex: 1,
              child: ListView.builder(
                  controller: _scrollController,
                  itemCount: widget.items.length,
                  itemBuilder: _itemBuilder),
            ),
            ToggleButtons(
                onPressed: (int index) {
                  setState(() {
                    for (int buttonIndex = 0;
                        buttonIndex < hasHeaders.length;
                        buttonIndex++) {
                      if (buttonIndex == index) {
                        hasHeaders[buttonIndex] = true;
                      } else {
                        hasHeaders[buttonIndex] = false;
                      }
                    }
                  });
                },
                children: [Text('headers on'), Text('headers off')],
                isSelected: hasHeaders)
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to reinitialize a new ScrollController (with a specified initial offset) every time the headers are toggled, as well as provide differing ValueKeys for the ListView. This resets the cached size calculations. While perhaps not as perfomant as an ideal solution (something like React-Virtualized's rowHeight callback might be nice), it doesn't seem to perform too badly in this simple example when at the top of the list.

It does perform badly when far down a long list, especially when there's differing item heights. Changing the heights of items can take seconds.  Related to this issue: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/52207

Here's the code

```dart
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp(
    items: List<String>.generate(10000, (i) => 'Item $i'),
  ));
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<String> items;
  MyApp({Key? key, required this.items}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  late ScrollController _scrollController = ScrollController();
  List<bool> hasHeaders = [true, false];
  int selectedIndex = 0;

  Widget _heading = Container(
    height: 50,
    color: Colors.amber,
    child: Text('heading'),
  );

  Widget _item({required int index}) {
    bool isSelected = index == selectedIndex;
    void _handleItemTap() {
      setState(() {
        print('setting index to $index');
        selectedIndex = index;
      });
      double futureOffset = 100.0 * index;
      if (hasHeaders[0]) {
        futureOffset += (index + 1) * 50;
      }
      _scrollController.animateTo(futureOffset,
          duration: Duration(milliseconds: 800), curve: Curves.ease);
      print('scrolling to $futureOffset');
    }

    return Container(
      height: 100.0,
      color: isSelected ? Colors.green : Colors.white,
      child: Material(
        color: isSelected ? Colors.green : Colors.white,
        child: InkWell(
          onTap: _handleItemTap,
          child: ListTile(
            title: Text('${widget.items[index]}'),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _itemBuilderWithHeaders(BuildContext context, int index) {
    return _itemBuilder(context, index, true);
  }

  Widget _itemBuilderWithoutHeaders(BuildContext context, int index) {
    return _itemBuilder(context, index, false);
  }

  Widget _itemBuilder(BuildContext context, int index, bool hasHeader) {
    if (hasHeader) {
      return Column(
        children: [_heading, _item(index: index)],
      );
    } else {
      return _item(index: index);
    }
  }

  ListView _list(bool withHeaders) {
    return ListView.builder(
        key: ValueKey(withHeaders ? 'listWithHeaders' : 'compactList'),
        controller: _scrollController,
        itemCount: widget.items.length,
        itemBuilder:
            withHeaders ? _itemBuilderWithHeaders : _itemBuilderWithoutHeaders);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final title = 'Long List';
    return MaterialApp(
      title: title,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(title),
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: [
            Flexible(
              flex: 1,
              child: hasHeaders[0] ? _list(true) : _list(false),
            ),
            ToggleButtons(
                onPressed: (int index) {
                  double initialScrollOffset = _scrollController.offset;
                  if (hasHeaders[0]) {
                    int numItemsAbove = _scrollController.offset ~/ 150;
                    initialScrollOffset =
                        initialScrollOffset - (numItemsAbove + 1) * 50;
                  } else {
                    int numItemsAbove = _scrollController.offset ~/ 100;
                    initialScrollOffset =
                        initialScrollOffset + numItemsAbove * 50;
                  }
                  setState(() {
                    for (int buttonIndex = 0;
                        buttonIndex < hasHeaders.length;
                        buttonIndex++) {
                      if (buttonIndex == index) {
                        hasHeaders[buttonIndex] = true;
                      } else {
                        hasHeaders[buttonIndex] = false;
                      }
                    }

                    _scrollController = ScrollController(
                        initialScrollOffset: initialScrollOffset);
                  });
                },
                children: [Text('headers on'), Text('headers off')],
                isSelected: hasHeaders)
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```